# Prefer overloaded function over the other when reference to class is passed, which implements interface

Tags: c++

This is what I am working with (roughly)

```
template<class t>
class Manager{
//this class has a internal map which you can use to store classes of 1 type with a key.
//This class is also a templated singelton (which means that you can call getInstance() for 
//any type like so: Manager<someType>::getInstance()
//...
public:
    void addComponent(int key, const t& newThing){
    //add to internal map
    }

    void addComponent(int key, AddsFriends<t>& newThing){
    //add newThing & Friends to map
    }
}

template<class t>
class AddsFriends<t>{
public:
   virtual void addFriends(int key){
   //add the Friend classes to the maps upon being called
   }
}
```

This is a exercise I came up with so its not really anything too logical. Basically when I get a Manager from any type I should be able to add a entry to it with a specified key and component (which it will copy upon insertion.) I can also retrieve the inserted classes using a get function (not shown above).

When a type is used that extends "AddsFriends" I want to be able to call "addFriends" with a key so any "Friend-instances" can be added to many types. This way I kinda want to make something where I can have a class called "Person" and have it add a "Hat" class to the corresponding manager with the same id when the person gets added (therefore every "person" inserted also causes a "hat" to be inserted). I hope this is understandable.

However, Im having trouble determining if this interface is implemented or not. I tried to do dynamic_cast and just check for an exception, but that would require loosing the const-expression -> makes insert statements longer (since I have to store the variable "just" for it to act as an initialiser instead of just calling the constructor in the add-function)

How could I get c++ to pick the correct function here?

EDIT:

Here is how I intend to use manager:

```
int key;
Manager<std::string>& stringManager = Manager<std::string>::getInstance();
stringManager.addComponent(key, "Hello there");

Manager<Foo>& fooManager = Manager<Foo>::getInstance();
fooManager.addComponent(key, Foo("Some init Params"));

class Foo: public AddsFriends<Foo>{
private:
    std::string *friendString = nullptr;
 //Other stuff
public:
    //Do constructor and whatever else you want
    virtual void addFriends(int key){
    //add the Friend classes to the maps upon being called
         Manager<std::string>& stringManager = Manager<std::string>::getInstance();
         stringManager.addComponent(key, "This belongs to the foo component!");
         //Note: The way I do this changed in my actual implementation, where I return a reference directly in the addComponent method. When I asked this question I was still using this function just because I didnt want to make the problem more complicated before I could get the old version to work. getNewest just return the reference to the newest component.
         this->friendString = &stringManager.getNewest();

    }

}
```

The reason why I want friends to be added in this way is so that I can have "components" that use the same functionality as other components through composition, but still make the "components" they use accessible through the proper manager. So lets say I have a component called "Cube" and a component called "Position". The cube holds the data that you need to represent a cube, but it also has a position assigned to it. If I just did regular composition with a "Position" attribute, it would work, but the Position wouldnt be in the PositionManager, like it should. This would result in a incomplete set of managed components and kinda ruins the point of having these managers in the first place :/.

Comment: "I hope this is understandable." I can only speak for myself, but I find code described in words extremely difficult to understand. It would be lot easier if you show the code that you would like to write together with the errors or any other trouble you encounter

Comment: it looks like you're using CRTP, are you sure you want it? maybe you should simply use a base (interface) class?

Comment: @appleapple yes. I do want that. Simply because that way I can keep the type-lock when I use just the interface as a paramter. If I find a solution that doesnt require using the interface as a parameter, ill remove the template from it

Comment: @user463035818 basically I am looking for a way to determine if the type-parameter implements a certain interface without locking any types out outfront (including pointer types & non-polymorphic types -> dynamic_cast wont work)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option, I think, will be to specialize `Manager`.

```
template <class t>
class Manager {
   public:
      void addComponent(int key, const t& newThing){
         //add to internal map
      }
};

template <class t>
class Manager<AddsFriends<t>> {
   public:
      void addComponent(int key, AddsFriends<t> const& newThing){
         //add newThing & Friends to map
      }
};
```

Comment: Yea this would work, except now I need to always call the Manager like so:

Manager<AddsFriends<ActualType>>::getInstance()

instead of

Manager<ActualType>::getInstance() 

which is less from ideal.


I could do it with dynamic_cast but that doesnt let me compile as soon as I use a pointer type as the type. I dont want to limit the types inserted at all, but merely react when the type inserted implements this interface

Comment: @MoustacheSpy, I don't think you need to do that. Perhaps you can add some code in your post indicating how you intend to use `Manager`.

Comment: @R Sahu I added more info to the question. I hope this is fine

Comment: @MoustacheSpy, I tried your code with the specialization I recommended. It did not work as expected. I need to dig a bit deeper to see if there is clean solution.